# Change server option in middleware

Tags: node.js, plugins, middleware, fastify

In Fastify I can specify instance options while creating it, e.g.

```
const fastify = require('fastify')({logger:true, disableRequestLogging: false});
```

Is it possible to do this in a middleware registered with the instance?

e.g. if I do something like

```
fastify.register(myPlugin);
```

and instance of `fastify` is passed to `myPlugin` - can I, for example change its `disableRequestLogging` value while in the middleware?

Comment: as in you want to enable/disable it as requests come in via the middleware plugin?

Comment: @matt Basically I want to set `disableRequestLogging` to `false` only when plugin is registered. Plugin will do its own custom request logging, so I need to disable the default one if it's active

Comment: gotcha. I think even then it may be too late to change things...

Answer (score 0):

The [`router`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/b4185cae72adc795d885b56e1ecb7630b0212d2f/fastify.js#L138) is the what relies on `disableRequestLogging` to switch on/off logging [for the request](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/b4185cae72adc795d885b56e1ecb7630b0212d2f/lib/route.js#L333-L335) and the [later response](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/master/lib/route.js#L326).

```
    if (disableRequestLogging === false) {
      childLogger.info({ req: request }, 'incoming request')
    }
```

The router does provide a [`setup` function](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/b4185cae72adc795d885b56e1ecb7630b0212d2f/lib/route.js#L68-L84) that allows `disableRequestLogging` to be changed. You can see `fastify.js` uses `router.setup()` late in initialisation [here to apply some new values](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/b4185cae72adc795d885b56e1ecb7630b0212d2f/fastify.js#L344-L351).

The problem is fastify doesn't provide access to `router` as part of it's [public API](https://github.com/fastify/fastify/blob/b4185cae72adc795d885b56e1ecb7630b0212d2f/fastify.js#L162-L163). Only functions like `fastify.get`/`.post`/`.route` etc which allow access to specific components of the router.

Short of modifying the source, I can't see a way. Not even something dodgey like  onkeypatching a function in due to the way fastify variables are scoped. Even if you could do that, it would be delving into undefined/untested behaviours.

Comment: You could probably disable response logging on the fly every request via `Reply.log[kDisableRequestLogging]`